# How to prove that the pre-order tree traversal algorithm terminates?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, algorithm-analysis, correctness-proof, induction

I see **structural induction** the usual way for proving an algorithm's **termination** property, but it's not that easy to prove by means of induction on a **tree** algorithm. Now I am struggling on proving that the pre-order tree traversal algorithm is terminable:

```
preorder(node)
  if node == null then return
  visit(node)
  preorder(node.left) 
  preorder(node.right)
```

How should I prove?

Comment: A for-beginner article proving several tree traversals: https://web.archive.org/web/20150412112722/http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~reltech/1992/92-10.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint (by Raphael):  How do you prove that the recursive factorial function terminates?

Answer (by Kejia): The recursive factorial function's universe is non-negative integers, which is countable and so well-found, and so it is very easy to prove with mathematical induction.

By analogy, we can find a mapping from trees to a well-founded universe so that a similar proof works.

> Our mapping is to the size of the subtree.
>  At each recursive call, the size of a subproblem (i.e. a subtree) is strictly decreasing and always non-negative. Therefore, we can proceed by induction.
>
>  Suppose (induction hypothesis) that the function on a tree of size of at most k terminates. Now consider an input tree with k+1 nodes...

Comment: Why is that sufficient? (I know the answer, but your post is a bit thin.)

Comment: @Joe yes, and how to prove?